How to Map a PostgreSQL BIT VARYING(7) Field to a Kotlin Entity Field in Hibernate?
I am having trouble mapping a PostgreSQL BIT VARYING(7) field to a Kotlin entity class using Hibernate. I can not modify the database schema. How can I map this field to Kotlin?
Here is a simplified SQL definition:
create table my_entity
(
    id        integer       default nextval('seq_myentity'::regclass) not null
        primary key,
    weekdays  bit varying(7)                                         not null
);

Here is my simplified Kotlin code:
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter
import jakarta.persistence.Column
import jakarta.persistence.Convert
import jakarta.persistence.Converter
import jakarta.persistence.Entity
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType
import jakarta.persistence.Id
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator
import jakarta.persistence.Table
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull
import java.util.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
open class MyEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "myentity_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "myentity_generator", sequenceName = "seq_myentity", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    open var id: Int? = null


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "weekdays", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit varying(7)")
    @Convert(converter = BitSetConverter2::class)
    open var weekdays: BitSet? = null

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other !is MyEntity) return false

        if (id != other.id) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return id ?: 0
    }
}

@Converter(autoApply = true)
class BitSetConverter : AttributeConverter<BitSet, String> {
    override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: BitSet?): String {
        return BitSetHelper.bitSetToString(attribute)
    }

    override fun convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: String?): BitSet {
        return BitSetHelper.stringToBitSet(dbData)
    }
}

object BitSetHelper {
    fun bitSetToString(attribute: BitSet?): String {
        if (attribute == null) return ""
        val sb = StringBuilder(attribute.length())
        for (i in 0 until attribute.length()) {
            sb.append(if (attribute[i]) '1' else '0')
        }
        return sb.toString()
    }

    fun stringToBitSet(dbData: String?): BitSet {
        val bitSet = BitSet()
        if (dbData == null || dbData.isEmpty()) return bitSet
        for (i in dbData.indices) {
            if (dbData[i] == '1') {
                bitSet.set(i)
            }
        }
        return bitSet
    }
}

And I am getting this error:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "weekdays" is of type bit varying but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Initially, I tried mapping it as a String, but it didn't work. After extensive research, I discovered the concept of converters, but I'm still unsure how to properly convert the BIT VARYING type. I attempted using a BitSetConverter to convert it to String, Byte, and Int, but none of these approaches were successful.
